# Is it more performant to have a single mongoDb document with large array, or one document per array element?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of events / notifications, and I need to keep track of which users the event is relevant for. I'm looking into two options:

1. Each event has a targets: [] array field.
2. Each event is duplicated, one for each target.

An event may be relevant for up to 3000 users.

Event object example:

```
{
  id: <UUID>,
  type: "newDocument",
  createdAt: <Date>,
  senderId: <UUID>,
  targets: <userId> OR [<userId>,<userId>]
}
```

**What would be the most performant solution?**